# After Exception the field reset or cleaned up

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

After creating an Exception i want to reset the field which is not happening since I tried many alternatives but it's worthless... for example:

```
@api.onchange('time_date')  
def onchange_date_time(self):

        print 'working till now ----------------------------'
        if self.time_date:
            time_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.time_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            if time_date<datetime.date.today():
                raise except_orm('Error','Please enter the correct date')
                self.time_date = None
            else:
                pass
```

The above code I am using it to create an Exception when the enter date is not today's date in a Hotel module here time_date refers to check in date, however it's creating an exception but the date field is not getting reset.

Comment: Why can you not do it before raising the exception?

Comment: Hi aa333 I tried that but it wasn't helpful .........

Comment: What do you mean by not helpful? What was the result? What were you expecting? Explaining your question quantifiably is a necessary step to get help on SO.

Comment: I want the field value to be reset once the exception occurred which is not happening it's showing the selected value after the exception....However I tried to reset it before raising the exception but it's not happening

Answer (score 1):

If you are using onchange(), you can use **warning** rather than exception.

Try this:-

```
    @api.onchange('time_date')
def _onchange_date_time(self):
    if self.time_date:
        time_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.time_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        if time_date<datetime.date.today():
            self.time_date = False
            return {
                'warning': {
                    'title': "Error",
                    'message': "Please enter the correct date",
                }
            } 
        else:
            pass
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Baiju Thanks for replying I tried to used warning instead of exception but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return {

         'warning': {'title': 'Error!', 'message': 'Please enter the correct date'},
          'value': {
                     'time_date': None,
                     'flat': None,
                    } 
                }
```